# for loop with unequal variables

Tags: r, variables, for-loop, if-statement

I have a 2 variables with various lengths. I want to create a for loop that only calculate the sum for two equal values. If the values aren't equal to each other, the variable b must be updated with +1. Is there a way to create this? I thougth something like this:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<- c(1,7,2,3,6,4,5)

j <- 1
test<- matrix()
for( i in 1:length(a)) {
if(a[i] == b[j]){
result <- a[i] + b[j] 
test[[i]]<-matrix(result)
j <- j + 1}
else {
j <- j +1
}

1 + 1 = TRUE
2 + 7 + FALSE +1
2 + 2 = TRUE
3 + 3 = TRUE 
4 + 6 = FALSE +1
4 + 4 = TRUE
5 + 5 = TRUE
```

Thank you all!

Comment: I don't really get it. With that data, and given the fact that every a is contained in b, why not just do `a*2`?

Comment: @Joris, this is a simple version of my real data. In the real loop i don't use the sum method!

Comment: Thought so. But you should specify that in your question. Next to that, pay attention to my comment on the accepted answer. The accepted answer can give a wrong solution in some cases. Also when a contains repeated values, the code given in the answer is buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is the right solution for this variables. The only requirement is that all values from variable a need to provent in variable b.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)  
b<- c(1,7,2,3,6,4,5)  

match(a,b)

test <- matrix()
for(i in 1:length(a)){      
if (a[i] == b[i]) {          
result <- a[i] + b[i]           
test[i]<- result          
}
else {
c<- which(b == a[i])
result <- a[i] + b[c]           
test[i]<- result          
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you are trying to do but how does this work?

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5) 
b<- c(1,7,2,3,6,4,5)

test<- matrix()
  for( i in 1:length(a)) {
    for (j in 1:length(b)){
      if (a[i] == b[j]) {
         result <- a[i] + b[j] 
         test[i]<- result
         break()
       }
     }
   }

 > test
 [1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

Comment: use `test <-numeric(length(a))`. Predefining the length will gain a lot in speed.

Comment: This does not work when `a <- c(1,2,3,5,4) ; b <- c(1,2,3,4,5)`. Outcome should be 2,4,6,10 and not 2,4,6,10,8 . add `x<-1`before test<- matrix() and `x <- j` before `break()`. loop `for(j in x:length(b))` instead of `1:length(b)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define what you expect a lot more clearly.  If all you want is to double the values of 'a' which appear in 'b' (since summing two equal things is twice one of them),
then  all you need is
    doubs<-vector()

```
j=1

for (i in 1:length(a)){

if (length(which(a[i]==b)) >0 ) {doubs[j]=2*a[i];j<-j+1}

}
```

But: do you only want to store the first match, or all matches? 
E.g.  a = 1 and b = c(1,2,1,3,1).
And you need to read up on "==" vs.  is.equal or you will one day be sorry.